# incompatible types: com.rh.host.Validator<T> cannot be converted to com.rh.host.Pool.Validator<T>

Tags: java, generics, pool

I using `generic object pooling` to reuse `Cipher` object.

**Eracom**

```
 Pool< Cipher> pool = PoolFactory.newBoundedBlockingPool(10, new CipherPicker("DESede/CBC/NoPadding"), new CipherPickerValidator());
```

**PoolFactory**

```
  public static <T> Pool<T> newBoundedBlockingPool(int size, ObjectFactory<T> factory, Validator<T> validator) {
        return new BoundedBlockingPool<T>(size, factory, validator);
    }
```

**Pool**

```
public interface Pool<T>
{
 T get();
 void shutdown();
 public boolean isValid(T t);
 public void invalidate(T t);
 }
}
```

**Validator**

```
public interface Validator<T>
 {

  public boolean isValid(T t);

  public void invalidate(T t);
 }
```

**CipherPickerValidator**

```
public final class CipherPickerValidator implements Validator <Cipher>
{

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Cipher t) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate(Cipher t) {
//       return false;
    }
}
```

I get error in `PoolFactory`. It shows a red line under `validator`.

**Error**

```
incompatible types: com.rh.host.Validator<T> cannot be converted to com.rh.host.Pool.Validator<T> where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in method <T>newBoundedBlockingPool(int,ObjectFactory<T>,com.rh.host.Validator<T>)
```

I follow [A Generic and Concurrent Object Pool](https://dzone.com/articles/generic-and-concurrent-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the article's code appears to have been munged.

The error is attempting to assign a

```
com.rh.host.Validator
```

to a

```
com.rh.host.Pool.Validator
```

Written like that it's obvious what has happened. You have two unrelated types both called `Validator`. The article appears to present a nested type in a file of its own.

So make sure you have only one definition for each name. And probably find a better presented article.